# Do you know if it's possible to compile a libgdx in Android (in an Android phone) without compiling it in native JAVA?

Tags: java, android, compilation, libgdx

I'm trying to begin programming with libgdx (in Windows XP with Eclipse for JAVA - Android) but, as every begining, nothing is clear and every doubt is a big problem. 
I have found some tutorials about how to begin to programming with libgdx, but every tutorial found says the same: you must create a PC project for compile the native JAVA code and then create another project for Android who needs the PC project.

It's possible to do it in a easier way (all in only one Android project)? If it's possible, how? It would be really slower? I run my Android projects in my device (a Motorola G) and it seems pretty fast.

All (kind) responses will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the project generator? http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew

You could use that and simply ignore the non-android projects it creates ,even delete the other ones you don't plan to use (not the main java one though) and run it via an android emulator/device.

You will probably still have to keep the main java project, libgdx is geared towards people that want to compile to multiple devices.

It's been over year since i've used libgdx and i don't recall this being one of the issues i had with it.

Comment: Maybe I should ask why it's necessary to do all this stuff with a desktop project. I can't understand why I need a desktop project for programming with android. When I install all files with the project generator it adds all sort of rubbish that I don't need (libgdx for html and so on). And, finally, I receave many errors after importing files... I'm lost, really.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I find is to actually just put a main method class in your libgdx project.  I have a wrapper project for android that invokes my libgdx project but if you look at the example in [superjumper source in github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/superjumper/superjumper/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/SuperJumperDesktop.java) you can see they just put a main method class within their libgdx project.

The android project then just delegates to this project.

Consider though, if you do run it directly from a project, you'll need to code in keyboard cursor keys which is pretty easy, you can follow the superjumper example [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/superjumper/superjumper/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/GameScreen.java) line 138.